# How to go through hashmap and compare key or value to scanner input?

Tags: java, hashmap, java.util.scanner

So I want to make this applet to train languages with. I made a Hashmap containing the Spanish words as keys and the English equivalents as values. For example:

```
HashMap<String, String> words = new HashMap<String, String>();
        words.put("dentista", "dentist");
        words.put("abogado", "lawyer");
        words.put("maestro", "teacher");
```

Now I want to train with those by first asking which language I choose to get asked in. If I say choose English (=values), I want my program to show me each key and wait for me to respond via scanner and compare my response to its key. Is something like this possible with HashMaps?
I started with this:

```
 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
 Collection<String> esp = words.keySet();
        for (String string : esp) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
        
        Collection<String> eng = words.values();
        for (String string : eng ) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
```

does anybody have tips? I've been at this for 4h now and debugging just means I delete every bit of progress I have.

Answer (score 0):

Java's hashmap is not designed for this. You can't ask it: "Hey, given this value, find me the associated key". All you can do is to just iterate through it. If you start having a few ten thousand entries this is quite inefficient.

Your best bet is to just make 2 hashmaps; one maps english to spanish and one maps spanish to english. You can derive the second one using a simple method, which loops through your spanish to english dictionary once and creates an english to spanish dictionary out of it. Alternatively, add the guava dependency and use guava's [BiMap](https://guava.dev/releases/23.6-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) which *is* a map that can go both ways.